# Returning bad credential in oauth2 implemention using spring boot 1.5

Tags: spring, spring-boot

As i am trying to create simple login in oauth2 implementation using spring boot. Unfortunately its not working, as i am newbie in spring 
My configuration

ApplicationStarter.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration

public class ApplicationStarter extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
     @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            return application.sources(ApplicationStarter.class);
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationStarter.class, args);
    }
}
```

ResourceServerConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration

@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "my_rest_api";

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           System.out.println("Inside ResourceServerConfiguration");
        http.
        anonymous().disable()
        .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/user/**")
        .and().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/user/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }

}
```

AuthorizationServerConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static String REALM="MY_OAUTH_REALM";

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
           System.out.println("Inside AuthorizationServerConfiguration");
        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("my-trusted-client")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
            .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
            .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
            .secret("secret")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(120).//Access token is only valid for 2 minutes.
            refreshTokenValiditySeconds(600);//Refresh token is only valid for 10 minutes.
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore).userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.realm(REALM+"/client");
    }

}
```

MethodSecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2SecurityConfiguration securityConfig;

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }
}
```

OAuth2SecurityConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration

@ComponentScan
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("inside OAuth2SecurityConfiguration : globalUserDetails()");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("bill").password("abc123").roles("ADMIN").and()
        .withUser("bob").password("abc123").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("inside OAuth2SecurityConfiguration : configure()");
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .anonymous().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("inside OAuth2SecurityConfiguration : authenticationManagerBean()");
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }


    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        System.out.println("inside OAuth2SecurityConfiguration : tokenStore()");
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler(TokenStore tokenStore){
        System.out.println("inside OAuth2SecurityConfiguration : userApprovalHandler()");
        TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler handler = new TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler();
        handler.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService));
        handler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore(TokenStore tokenStore) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("inside OAuth2SecurityConfiguration : approvalStore()");
        TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
        store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        return store;
    }

}
```

[image]

Please do correct me where i am went wrong? whether any more configuration needed or not?

as i followed 
http://websystique.com/spring-security/secure-spring-rest-api-using-oauth2/
as reference.

spring boot log

> 2017-10-26 11:15:07.851 DEBUG 21456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Bound request context to
>   thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@1f2fcd1 2017-10-26
>   11:15:07.851 DEBUG 21456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant
>   [pattern='/css/**'] 2017-10-26 11:15:07.851 DEBUG 21456 ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking
>   match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/css/**' 2017-10-26
>   11:15:07.851 DEBUG 21456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant
>   [pattern='/js/**'] 2017-10-26 11:15:07.851 DEBUG 21456 ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking
>   match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/js/**' 2017-10-26
>   11:15:07.851 DEBUG 21456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant
>   [pattern='/images/**'] 2017-10-26 11:15:07.851 DEBUG 21456 ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking
>   match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/images/**' 2017-10-26
>   11:15:07.851 DEBUG 21456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant
>   [pattern='/webjars/**'] 2017-10-26 11:15:07.851 DEBUG 21456 ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking
>   match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/webjars/**' 2017-10-26
>   11:15:07.851 DEBUG 21456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant
>   [pattern='/**/favicon.ico'] 2017-10-26 11:15:07.851 DEBUG 21456 ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking
>   match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
>   2017-10-26 11:15:07.851 DEBUG 21456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant
>   [pattern='/error'] 2017-10-26 11:15:07.851 DEBUG 21456 ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking
>   match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/error' 2017-10-26
>   11:15:07.851 DEBUG 21456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found 2017-10-26
>   11:15:07.851 DEBUG 21456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant
>   [pattern='/**'] 2017-10-26 11:15:07.851 DEBUG 21456 ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request
>   '/oauth/token' matched by universal pattern '/**' 2017-10-26
>   11:15:07.851 DEBUG 21456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : matched 2017-10-26
>   11:15:07.851 DEBUG 21456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        :
>   /oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=bill&password=abc123 at
>   position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter:
>   'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter' 2017-10-26 11:15:07.851 DEBUG 21456
>   --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=bill&password=abc123 at
>   position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter:
>   'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter' 2017-10-26 11:15:07.852 DEBUG 21456
>   --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=bill&password=abc123 at
>   position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter:
>   'HeaderWriterFilter' 2017-10-26 11:15:07.852 DEBUG 21456 ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        :
>   /oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=bill&password=abc123 at
>   position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter:
>   'LogoutFilter' 2017-10-26 11:15:07.852 DEBUG 21456 ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to
>   match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET] 2017-10-26 11:15:07.852 DEBUG
>   21456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  :
>   Request 'POST /oauth/token' doesn't match 'GET /logout 2017-10-26
>   11:15:07.852 DEBUG 21456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant
>   [pattern='/logout', POST] 2017-10-26 11:15:07.852 DEBUG 21456 ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking
>   match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/logout' 2017-10-26
>   11:15:07.852 DEBUG 21456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant
>   [pattern='/logout', PUT] 2017-10-26 11:15:07.869 DEBUG 21456 ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request
>   'POST /oauth/token' doesn't match 'PUT /logout 2017-10-26 11:15:07.869
>   DEBUG 21456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant
>   [pattern='/logout', DELETE] 2017-10-26 11:15:07.869 DEBUG 21456 ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request
>   'POST /oauth/token' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout 2017-10-26
>   11:15:07.869 DEBUG 21456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found 2017-10-26
>   11:15:07.869 DEBUG 21456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        :
>   /oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=bill&password=abc123 at
>   position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter:
>   'BasicAuthenticationFilter' 2017-10-26 11:15:07.869 DEBUG 21456 ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Basic
>   Authentication Authorization header found for user 'my-trusted-client'
>   2017-10-26 11:15:07.869 DEBUG 21456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt
>   using
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
>   2017-10-26 11:15:07.869 DEBUG 21456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : User 'my-trusted-client'
>   not found 2017-10-26 11:15:07.869 DEBUG 21456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Authentication request for
>   failed:
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException:
>   Bad credentials 2017-10-26 11:15:07.869 DEBUG 21456 ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not
>   injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@1ff799
>   2017-10-26 11:15:07.869 DEBUG 21456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now
>   cleared, as request processing completed 2017-10-26 11:15:07.869 DEBUG
>   21456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    :
>   Cleared thread-bound request context:
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@1f2fcd1 2017-10-26
>   11:15:07.870 DEBUG 21456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name
>   'dispatcherServlet' processing POST request for [/auth/error]
>   2017-10-26 11:15:07.870 DEBUG 21456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method
>   for path /error 2017-10-26 11:15:07.870 DEBUG 21456 ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning
>   handler method [public
>   org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity>
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
>   2017-10-26 11:15:07.870 DEBUG 21456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance
>   of singleton bean 'basicErrorController' 2017-10-26 11:15:07.874 DEBUG
>   21456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  :
>   Written [{timestamp=Thu Oct 26 11:15:07 IST 2017, status=401,
>   error=Unauthorized, message=Bad credentials, path=/auth/oauth/token}]
>   as "application/json" using
>   [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@32886a]
>   2017-10-26 11:15:07.874 DEBUG 21456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
>   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned
>   to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming
>   HandlerAdapter completed request handling 2017-10-26 11:15:07.874
>   DEBUG 21456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
>   : Successfully completed request

gradle.build

```
> /*  * This build file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.  *  *
> This generated file contains a sample Java Library project to get you
> started.  * For more details take a look at the Java Libraries chapter
> in the Gradle  * user guide available at
> https://docs.gradle.org/3.5/userguide/java_library_plugin.html  */
> buildscript {
>     ext { springBootVersion = '1.5.7.RELEASE' }
>     repositories { mavenCentral() }
>     dependencies { classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
> } } // Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
> apply plugin: 'java' apply plugin: 'eclipse' apply plugin:
> 'org.springframework.boot' apply plugin: 'war'
> 
> 
> sourceCompatibility = 1.8 // In this section you declare where to find
> the dependencies of your project repositories {
>     // Use jcenter for resolving your dependencies.
>     // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.    // jcenter()    mavenCentral() }
> 
> dependencies {
>     // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
>     //api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
>     //providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:1.5.2.RELEASE'
>     // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
>     implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:21.0'
> 
>     // Use JUnit test framework
>     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
>     
>    
>     // compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:1.4.1.RELEASE")
>     // compile("org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.0.2.RELEASE")
> //  
> compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:3.2.0.RELEASE")
>     //    compile("org.gitlab4j:gitlab4j-api:4.6.0")
>      //    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:1.5.2.RELEASE")
>          
>     compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
>     compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
>        compile('org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2')
>        compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-config')
>     compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
>     providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
>    
>     testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') }
```

Comment: what is your context path?

Comment: server.context-path=/auth

Comment: Could you follow my answer and try again? let me know the status.

Comment: its not working..still the same

Answer (score 0):

Change your authorization server config like that

*`AuthorizationServerConfiguration.java`*

```
@Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
           System.out.println("Inside AuthorizationServerConfiguration");
        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("my-trusted-client")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
            .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
            .scopes("read", "write", "trust").resourceIds("my_rest_api")
            .secret("secret")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(120).//Access token is only valid for 2 minutes.
            refreshTokenValiditySeconds(600);//Refresh token is only valid for 10 minutes.
    }
```

Here changes is I put a resourceIds after scope and that resource id will be same as Resources server's `RESOURCE_ID`.

You declared in ResourceServerConfiguration such like that

```
private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "my_rest_api";
```

So putting the string in authorization server can solve your problem I believe.
Thanks.

Comment: If you are seeing this tutorial then may be you are missing this line `resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);` in resource server.

Comment: but that function is not there..instead of that any alternative is there?

Comment: I see it's still there `@Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
    }`

Comment: ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer is not supporting .stateless(false);

Comment: If it is a maven project then, please share your `pom.xml`.

Comment: its gradle project

Comment: I didn't so much idea about gradle, but I found some dependency mismatch in your `gradle.build`. Goto here http://sagioto.github.io/maven2gradle/ and put your followed tutorial pom and observe which dependency is missing in gradle. One observation, If it is spring boot project then why you  packaged into `war` file? it should be `jar` file.